# Remove ADD TO CART button after adding product to the cart in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Hello I am trying to make a simple ecommence website with woocommerce. I want to limit the number of products purchase. Means if a product is added to cart then "Add to cart" button should be removed.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want a user can't buy more than 1 quantity of product at a time? or you want to control the total purchases of a particular product?

Comment: Yes i want to control the over all purchase of the product. Currently use can buy 1 product and then he/she try to add, it dosent allow per order. So now i want to hide the button as well.